# How does jquery's show/hide function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I have a bit of an issue with a toggle visibility function which operates on the `hidden` attribute of an element. Trouble is, this lacks browser compatibility..

```
function hide(e) {$(e).hidden=true;}    
function show(e) {$(e).hidden=false;}
```

Googling this issue I came across the method of toggling the style.display property, like so..

```
function toggle(e) {
document.getElementById(e).style.display = (document.getElementById(e).style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";
}
```

..but this seems sub-optimal, because you can't have a generic show/hide function that sets  the display property to `block`. What if the element  in question sometimes is supposed to have a `inline` or something?

How does for example jQuery solve this issue?

Comment: Go read the [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L19) to find out ;-)

Comment: @Didier Ghys, I did, I was just hoping someone would explain it to me :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It stores the old `display` value in a `data` attribute called `olddisplay` and then uses the value of that to restore it when showing the element again. [See the implementation here](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.fn.show). You can check the implementation of any jQuery method on that site.

In the following code snippets I've annotated the important line with a `//LOOK HERE` comment.

The important part of the `show` method:

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    elem = this[i];

    if (elem.style) {
        display = elem.style.display;

        if (display === "" || display === "none") {
            elem.style.display = jQuery._data(elem, "olddisplay") || ""; //LOOK HERE
        }
    }
}
```

When [hiding an element](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.fn.hide) it firstly stores the current `display` value in a `data` attribute:

```
for (var i = 0, j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (this[i].style) {
        var display = jQuery.css(this[i], "display");

        if (display !== "none" && !jQuery._data(this[i], "olddisplay")) {
            jQuery._data(this[i], "olddisplay", display); //LOOK HERE
        }
    }
}
```

And then simply sets the `display` property to `none`. The important part:

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    if (this[i].style) {
        this[i].style.display = "none"; //LOOK HERE
    }
}
```

**Note**

The above code is taken from jQuery version 1.6.2 and is obviously subject to change in later versions.