# Javascript vs. CSS for swapping elements

Tags: javascript, css

I have a rather lengthy (~100 fields) form that has certain elements which are toggled between a "quick" and a "full" quote.  This toggles 75 of the fields from hidden to visible.  Currently, I do this via some simple jQuery:

```
jQuery('.full_quote').show();
jQuery('.quick_quote').hide();
```

I realized that this could be accomplished in a different way using CSS to do the work for me:

```
## Javascript:
  jQuery('#quote_form').toggleClass("full_quote quick_quote");

## CSS:
  form.toggle-form.full_quote .quick_quote {display: none;}
  form.toggle-form.quick_quote .full_quote {display: none;}
```

**So the bulk of the question is:**  Which is better to use when performance is concerned?

My initial thought is that the overhead of iterating over the results in jQuery will take more time than the CSS.  I do not have a way to test this, however, so I'm curious the community's experience.

Comment: I'd go with CSS whenever possible.

Comment: Found this test that was already done: http://jsperf.com/jquery-show-hide-vs-css-display-none-block/2

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization to me. You'll need to be changing display states on a *massive* number of elements to ever notice a performance hit using either method.

Comment: I've actually seen performance hits in IE on forms of only 50 fields with 40 of them swapping out.  Firefox and Chrome handle it better, of course.

Comment: @JackM., did you analyze the code to be certain that the bottleneck was with `show` and `hide`, and that it wasn't some other looping operation? If I had to guess, I'd say that the performance was poor due to a couple inefficient selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than defining new custom classes, or using jQuery's [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show) and [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) methods, I'd actually advise a third option.

Add a [`[hidden]`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-hidden-attribute) attribute to whatever element needs to be hidden, and remove the attribute when it needs to be shown:

<sub>JS:</sub>

```
$('.foo').attr('hidden', true);
```

To make sure that this is supported cross browser, you'll need to add a bit of CSS:

<sub>CSS:</sub>

```
[hidden] {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

[This also gives you the ability to override how "hidden" elements are styled, which can be useful for debugging.](http://jsfiddle.net/sFsAG/)

When you want to show the element, simply remove the `[hidden]` attribute:

<sub>JS:</sub>

```
$('.foo').attr('hidden', false);
```

It would be nice if jQuery implemented `show` and `hide` to utilize `[hidden]`, instead developers need to take care when using `show` as it will override any stylesheet declarations for `display` when it adds a `display` style inline.

Comment: Nice answer! I'm going to start using this.

Answer (score 0):

Both are essentially the same. JQuery does a very similar the same logic internally. (See [How does jquery's show/hide function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970184/how-does-jquerys-show-hide-function-work)). And it is not like your CSS apprach does not use javascript at all (in that case, it would be the better option)

So,

```
jQuery('.full_quote').show();
jQuery('.quick_quote').hide();
```

makes sense (you are using JQuery anyway, why not use all of its functions) s a lot more readable, and