# What is the JavaScript equivalent of jQuery's hide() and show()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple hide and show jQuery code and I want to ask if there is equivalent of this to JavaScript? Here's my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myButton").hide();
  $("#1").click(function() {
    $("#myButton").show();
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
      $("#myButton").hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option id="1">Science</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Click" id="myButton" />
```

I have followed some codes from the comments below but they are not working:

```html
<script>
  document.getElementById('myButton').style.display = 'none';

  function selectOptionsupdated(select) {
    document.getElementById('myButton').style.display = 'block';
  }
</script>

<select onSelect="selectOptionsupdated(this)">
  <option id="1">Science</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Click" id="myButton" />
```

What I want is at first the button is hidden, and when I click the `<option>` tag "Science" the button appears and when I click the button, the button is hidden after it is being clicked. And what if there are more `<option>` tags?

Comment: It's normally just setting and clearing the `display: none` style on elements I think.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614622/equivalent-of-jquery-hide-to-set-visibility-hidden

Comment: @stuartd that's not me

Comment: [Exact and reliable solution about how jQuery hide/show works](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8970184/1671639)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

this is simple

```
document.getElementById('myElement').style.display = 'block'; // show
document.getElementById('myElement').style.display = 'none'; // hide
```

add a `onSelect="selectOptionsupdated(this)` in your select

then

```
function selectOptionsupdated(select){
//do your stuff here  
}
```

Comment: so for my select tag `var select1 = document.getElementById('1');` how to trigger when the option in select tag is clicked? should i use if else statement?

Comment: like this? `<select onSelect="selectOptionsupdated(this)">
<option id="1">Science</option>
</select>` is it ok if there are more `<option>` tags? Sorry still learning.

Comment: @But there is a problem, it won't work. I edited my question about it.

Comment: you want to it in javascript or jquery

Comment: You can't rely on `display` property (it can be any of `inline`, `inline-block`, `flex`, etc..)  If you want to handle it dynamically then check this [ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8970232/1671639)

Answer (score 4):

```
var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');

//hide
myButton.style.display = 'none';

//show
myButton.style.display = 'block';
```

**Update**
for your select tag..try this

**html**

```
<select id="list">
<option id="1">Science</option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
var list = document.getElementById('select');

list.addEventListener('change', listSelect, false);

function listSelect(){    
    var selected = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;//Selected option value    //hide
    myButton.style.display = 'none';

    //show
    myButton.style.display = 'block'; 
}
```

Comment: so for my select tag `var select1 = document.getElementById('1');` how to trigger when the option in select tag is clicked? should i use if else statement?

Comment: @Abhidev: The JS code part was formatted as blockquote. I have changed it to code format now. Please feel free to roll it back if you have any concerns.

Comment: hey thanx @Harry...tried changing it to code format but stackoverflow said there are no changes in the code so it didn't allow. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("button").style.visibility="visible|hidden|collapse|inherit";
```

Comment: It is always better to add an explanation to the answer mate. It will make it clearer for both OP and any future readers. Also, I think you are suggesting the use of one of those values and not all in a `|` separated format.

Comment: not op but visibilty:hidden still takes space on page unlinke display:none https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_visibility&preval=hidden