# External + Inline Styles vs. External Only

Tags: jquery, html, css

## The Question + Overview

Below are two snippets containing a `div` being hidden initially, then shown with the click of a `button` and jQuery's `.show()`. Both `div`s have the style `display: grid;` being applied by external style sheet. The difference is as follows:

In example 1, inline specificity overrules the external style sheet. Grid layout **is** retained when div is shown.

In example 2, the `display: grid;` is being overridden by the cascade. Grid layout is **not** retained when div is shown.

It seems to me that both of the below snippets should have the same outcome, as both `display: grid;` styles are being overridden - albeit in *seemingly* slightly different ways.

What is happening here to cause the first example to work, and the second to break the grid layout?

I would prefer a technical, low level explanation if possible.

I included the jQuery tag in the off chance it's jQuery doing some magic I don't know about.

## Example 1: Inline + External Styles

In the following snippet, I have set the display of a div to be `display: grid;` in an external style sheet.

I also set the display of the same div to `display: none;` inline.

I then show the div using jQuery's `.hide()` function, and the div retains its grid layout.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#show-div').click(function() {
    $('#inline-style-div').show();
  });
});
```

```css
#inline-style-div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
}

.grid-number {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

.grid-number:nth-child(even) {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #333;
}

#show-div {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="inline-style-div" style="display: none;">
  <h5 class="grid-number">1</h5>
  <h5 class="grid-number">2</h5>
  <h5 class="grid-number">3</h5>
  <h5 class="grid-number">4</h5>
  <h5 class="grid-number">5</h5>
  <h5 class="grid-number">6</h5>
</div>

<button type="button" id="show-div">Show the div</button>
```

## Example 2: External Styles Only

In this snippet - with all else being equal - I have set the aforementioned div's display to `display: grid;` and `display: none;` sequentially in the external style sheet.

When I show the div in this example, the div does not retain its grid layout.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#show-div').click(function() {
    $('#external-style-div').show();
  });
});
```

```css
#external-style-div {
  display: grid;
  display: none;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
}

.grid-number {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

.grid-number:nth-child(even) {
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #333;
}

#show-div {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="external-style-div">
  <h5 class="grid-number">1</h5>
  <h5 class="grid-number">2</h5>
  <h5 class="grid-number">3</h5>
  <h5 class="grid-number">4</h5>
  <h5 class="grid-number">5</h5>
  <h5 class="grid-number">6</h5>
</div>

<button type="button" id="show-div">Show the div</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery's `.show()` is roughly equivalent to calling `.css( "display", "block" )`, except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a display value of `inline`, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed `inline`.

In your first example, jQuery notices that the inline display value is set to `none`, so it removes that and lets the cascade take effect (thanks @Alohci).

In your second example, jQuery notices that the initial display value is set to `none` (ignoring the first assignment directly before it, as it has no idea about this), and so assumes that you want it set to `block` when you use `show()`.

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/show/#entry-longdesc)

And further reading: [How does jquery's show/hide function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970184/how-does-jquerys-show-hide-function-work) (similar question)

Comment: That makes sense, however, it seems to me that in both examples, jQuery should cache `display: none;` as that is the last style being applied to each `div`. Perhaps jQuery is looking at a cached stylesheet rather than the DOM element, effectively causing it to ignore the inline style, and that is why it only sees `display: grid` in the first example?

Comment: Just edited to include a bit about that :) It's so it doesn't confuse itself, as it would set the inline style to display:none; when you use `hide()`

Comment: @CoryNorell have you tried it with just setting the inline style to 'grid' with no external styles? I'm interested to know the result!

Comment: " jQuery notices that the initial display value is set to grid" No it doesn't. In this case it merely removes the `display:none` from the style attribute and lets the cascade take effect. It won't remember that the display is grid unless hide() is called.

Comment: I have. I stand by my comment.

Comment: @markmoxx I don't think that would be a very useful experiment in this case, only because I'm not calling `.hide()` anywhere. If I was, then I'm quite sure the div would retain its grid layout, since the act of calling `.hide()` would cache the `display` value. But in this example, I want the div hidden on page load, only to be shown with the click of a button.